# How should I prune a copper beech sapling?

Tags: trees, pruning

I have a sapling from my parents' copper beech that I dug up from their yard.  I planted it in our yard about 3 years ago.  It now is about 9" tall and I wonder if I should prune it to force branching.  It has about a dozen leaves and appears healthy.

If it should be pruned, where do I cut it?  Below or above leaves?

Comment: Please add a photo as it may help people say **how** to prune it, not just if it should be pruned. Welcome to the site!

Answer (score 6):

Copper beeches ([*Fagus sylvatica* Purpurea](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fagus_sylvatica)) are simply reddish varieties of the European or common beech (*Fagus sylvatica*).

These trees grow happily and abundantly in many European forests, for example right where I live, in the Black Forest in Germany. In a few decades the spindly saplings can grow into large, majestic trees - without any pruning.

So no, there is no *need* to prune if you plan to let nature take its course.

Should you have specific plans as far as future shape is concerned, you *may* prune if required. My gut feeling, however, would be to simply let it grow for a few more years before taking any action (if you intend to cut).